# Codename One online compiler and runner

Tags: codenameone

On the web there are several free tools to include a Java compiler and runner in a blog.
They could be useful inside teaching articles targeted to beginners. The most useful tools are the ones in which the sample code can be modified by the blog reader.

Of course these kind of tools makes sense only for simple examples.

Sometimes, in the free time, I like blogging about programming. Does it exist or could it exist an online Codename One compiler and runner that can be included in a blog?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something on our to-do list but it doesn't exist yet. We have most of the tools in place so implementing this using the JavaScript port would be relatively simple.